# Rename DNG and associated JPG in one go

Tags: exiftool

I have a folder full of DNG and JPG files like

```
IMGP0001.DNG
IMGP0001.JPG
```

and I want to rename them to

```
20190725-133012-IMGP0001.dng
20190725-133012-IMGP0001.jpg
```

respectively.

I am currently using these exiftool args

```
 exiftool -d '%Y%m%d-%H%M%S-%%f.%%le' '-filename<CreateDate' '-FileCreateDate<CreateDate' '-FileModifyDate<CreateDate' -fileOrder DateTimeOriginal -ext mp4 -ext jpg -ext heic -ext mov -ext dng ./**/*
```

It handles a bit more then DNG and JPG files and I'd like to keep it that way, since my folders can be mixed with different image and video format files.

I think I'd have to specify a source for the EXIF data extraction, which would be the DNG or JPG (they seem to have the exact some createDate in them). But in case a MOV or MP4 would have to be renamed, the `tagsFromSource` arg might not work.

Comment: This "question" has no question.

Comment: Not in one go... After renaming the JPGs, you can rename the DNGs to assume the name of the JPG they are associated with: `for d in *.dng; do echo mv $d $(basename *$(basename $d .dng).jpg .jpg).dng ;done`

Comment: I recommend you taking this to Stackoverflow as its not all that related to photography. Writing a program such as this is quite easy in eg Python.

Comment: Where are the files that you want to rename stored ?

Comment: Are you asking if you can rename the .DNG files based upon the `CreateDate` in the .JPG file (or vice versa)? Does one of the file not have a `CreateDate` value?  I would think it would be easier to make sure both files have proper timestamps, but take a look at [this exiftool forums post](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php?topic=1423.0) for some details on how to rename both files based upon metadata in one of the files.  You may have to use a separate command to handle the video files, though.

Comment: I was about to compose an answer to suggest using the 'rename' command, to something like rename "s/$BASENAME/$DATE-$BASENAME/" * but I'm not sure if that answers whatever your question is.

Comment: I figured out the DNG and JPG contain the exact same timestamps so I can just rename them based on their EXIF info which turns out to work great.
Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I have used for all my renaming needs, images and general files, [Bulk Rename Utility](https://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php). Works like a charm for me every time. You can make pretty complex bulk changes with it.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Thanks. I prefer a command line tool to run it headless, though.

Comment: Bulk Rename Utility also has a command line tool. Check their website for more details.

Comment: @IanTrolles Given the `./**/*` in the question, and the reference to running "headless", OP is likely *not* using Windows, so the program you recommend wouldn't work.

Comment: If the OP uses Linux there is pyRenamer and if Mac there is Transnomino, if Finder itself cannot get the job done.